# valid if an object already exists in coreData swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

I have a record of students and grades, where it is saved:

- Name
- Spanish rating
- science grade
- math qualification
- physical qualification
  etc.
  My question is how can I check if a student has already been registered, all this is done with CoreData.
  I want to avoid duplicate records.

I want to use the name to check if a record with that same name already exists or not.
if it already exists, an alert is launched and if not, it is saved.

I have little time programming.

in this way the data is saved in CoreData.

[data register.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtZEb.png)

```
    private func saveStudent(){
            do{
                let currentStudent = Student(context: self.context)
                currentStudent.name = self.name
                currentStudent.spanish = self.spanish
                currentStudent.science = self.science
                currentStudent.math = self.math
                currentStudent.physical = self.physical
                currentStudent.average = self.average
                try context.save()
                SCLAlertView().showSuccess("Registrado", subTitle: "Estudiante registrado.", closeButtonTitle: "Aceptar", animationStyle: .bottomToTop)
            }catch{
                SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Error al guardar los datos.", closeButtonTitle: "Aceptar", animationStyle: .bottomToTop)
            }
    }
```

so the data from Core data is retrieved, an array is filled and the array fills a tableView.

```
Swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: - Private
    
    private var arrayOfRatings = [Student]()
    private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        recuperarDatos()
    }
  
    
    private func recuperarDatos(){
        do{
            try self.arrayOfRatings = self.context.fetch(Student.fetchRequest())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }catch{
            SCLAlertView().showError("Error", subTitle: "Error al recuperar datos.", closeButtonTitle: "Aceptar", animationStyle: .bottomToTop)
        }
    }
```

[retrieve data and reload tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUhfo.png)

my problem is that it should not be possible to register 2 students with the same name.
Before registering a new student I want to check if it has not been saved before.

Comment: You'll need a predicate of some kind it is impossible to help you with the code you have provided. Give it a try and let us know where you run into issues with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Fistly: I wouldn't take the name as an unique identifier. It's pretty common to have multiple persons with the same name (think of having twins in a same class, or two even unrelated people with common family names). You could fetch before saving for that unique identifier if that entity already exists in CoreData before saving. But it also means that you always need to have all grades, and can't modify one, is that what you want?